# Recursive Sort for a Stack in Python

Tags: python, sorting, oop, recursion, stack

I am learning recursion and am tasked with sorting an array. My study material is in Java and I am coding into Python myself.
I made a Stack class with few common methods and a unique sort_s method that should use recursion to sort the Stack. I have a helper fucntion to execute the Induction step in the 'IBH-method'.
My sort_s method is giving a name error. I suspect taking the function out of the class could solve the issue, but is there any way to keep the methods within the class.
The error message and code is printed below. Thank you in advance for your help.

> NameError 
> Traceback (most recent call last) 
>  in () 
> 60   test.push(8) 
> 61 
> ---> 62   sort_s(test)
> 63   print(test)
>
> NameError: name 'sort_s' is not defined

```
# Sort a stack using recursion

class Stack:
  def __init__(self, arr=[]):
    self.stack = []
    for ele in arr:
      self.stack.append(ele)

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.stack)

  def __str__(self):
    res = ''
    for each in self.stack:
      res += str(each) + ' '
    return res

  def get_stack(self):
    return self.stack

  def push(self, number):
    self.stack.append(number)

  def pop(self):
    ele = self.stack[-1]
    self.stack.pop()
    return ele

  def tail(self):
    tail = self.stack[-1]
    print(tail)

  def sort_s(self, s: Stack):
    if len(s.stack) <= 1: # Base Condition
      return s.stack
    temp = s.pop() # Hypothesis
    sort_s(s.stack) 
    return self.ordered_insert(s.stack, temp) # Induction
    

  def ordered_insert(self, arr, temp):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
      if arr[i] > temp:
        arr.insert(i, temp)
        break
      elif arr[-1] < temp:
        arr.append(temp)
    return arr
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
  test = Stack([0, 5, 1])
  print(test)
  test.tail()
  test.push(3)
  y = test.pop()
  print(f'{10+y}')
  print(test)
  test.push(6)
  test.push(9)
  test.push(8)

  sort_s(test)
  print(test)
```

Comment: So, notice how you arent using any of the self parameters in sort_s? Your self is already instanceof stack, why not run the sort on it directly? Also if you do that then you can call it using `test.sort_s()`

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a recursive sort, since most of the work is being done in `ordered_insert` and that's written iteratively -- also, if the idea is that this is a stack, an insertion at an arbitrary point isn't a valid operation (a stack just pushes and pops).

Comment: @DownloadPizza Thank you. I was able to modify the code to make it work. I didn't realize that I just need one attribute.
  def sort_s(self):
    if len(self.stack) <= 1: # Base Condition
      return self.stack
    temp = self.pop() # Hypothesis
    self.sort_s()
    return self.ordered_insert(self.stack, temp) # Induction

Comment: @Samwise Recursion is used to pop the stack into a single item array, only then does the iterative function take over. If you a way for me to make it completely recursive I will be greatly appreaciative :)

Comment: Google “recursive sort stack”: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-a-stack-using-recursion/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DownloadPizza, I was able to correct the sort_s function.

```
def sort_s(self):
    if len(self.stack) <= 1: # Base Condition 
        return self.stack 
   temp = self.pop() # Hypothesis 
   self.sort_s() 
   return self.ordered_insert(self.stack, temp) # Induction
```

Comment: In method `ordered_insert` why is `elif arr[-1] < temp:` inside the for loop? Shouldn't this be done as an alternative to the for loop?

Comment: Method `ordered_insert` is O(n) complexity, making the overall sort process O(n**2).  You could improve `ordered_insert` by using a binary insertion sort, which has a complexity of `log(n)`, making the overall process `O(n*log(n))`.